# .htaccess ignoring RewriteRule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm having trouble with my RewriteRule logic in my .htaccess file.

My query looks like this:

**domain/recipe/show?id=2**

And I want it to look like this:

**domain/recipe/2/show**

My .htaccess file looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} recipe/(.*)
RewriteRule show/(.*) recipe/show?id=$1
```

I've been staring at this for so long, and I just can't see the problem.There is nothing else in my htaccess file.

Answer (score 0):

There's a difference in your question between

> /recipe/2/show

and your rule

> show/(.*)

or `show/2`

If the URL in the question is valid, the rule should rather look like

```
RewriteRule ^recipe/(.*?)/show$ recipe/show?id=$1 [L]
```